# Do I need to apply both 32 bit and 64 bit versions of a .NET Framework update?

Tags: .net, .net-3.5, hotfix

There's a post-.NET 3.5 SP1 update which comes in x86 and x64 flavours:

The KB article is here:

> [List of the issues that are addressed by the Application Compatibility Update for the .NET Framework 3.5 SP1](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/958484/)

There are two possible updates:

> [NDP35SP1-KB958484-x86.exe](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=B9DE7937-2C12-4F16-AD66-A31B83931953&displaylang=en)
>   [NDP35SP1-KB958484-x64.exe](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=98E83614-C30A-4B75-9E05-0A9C3FBDD20D&displaylang=en&displaylang=en)

Will the 64 bit edition also update the 32 bit .NET Framework that's installed on Windows 2008/Vista 64 bit?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To expand on "matt b"'s answer, the 64-bit .NET Framework updates that Microsoft provides will always update both versions of the framework (native 64-bit and the "WOW64" 32-bit framework).

Comment: Appreciated...it's late and I'm thinking too deeply :)

Answer (score 1):

Your CPU is either 64 bit or 32 bit.

Do you have a 64 bit CPU? Install the x64 flavor.
Do you have a 32 bit CPU? Install the x86 flavor.